# JFrame Eclipse No me aparece las opciones Sources y Design

Tags: java, java-swing, eclipse, interfaz-gráfica, interface

He estado usando JFrame en clase y me sale la barra de Sources y Design pero al exportar el proyecto en mi casa Eclipse no me muestra esas opciones.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como hago para que me aparezcan. Tengo instalado Window Builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**¿Qué puedo hacer si no veo la pestaña Diseño (Design) o Código (Source) cuando edito una ventana?**

Es importante saber que `Eclipse` recuerda el último tipo de editor utilizado con un archivo. Si no ves la pestaña Diseño, significa que estás utilizando el Editor Java estándar de `Eclipse` en lugar del `WindowBuilder Editor`.

Debes abrir el archivo con `WindowBuilder Editor` y verás las pestañas "Source" y "Design".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debes tener en cuenta que `Eclipse` solo permitirá tener un archivo abierto con un editor a la vez, por lo que es posible que deba cerrar cualquier editor existente antes de abrirlo con `WindowBuilder Editor`.

Revisa [Eclipse - FAQ](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wb.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Ffaq.html)